# Set values in array with equal distance (as far as possible)

Tags: matlab, vector

I need to set m values in a vector with n elemetns to 1 and the distance between the ones should be similar.

For example assume a vector with 25 elements and we want to set 7 elements to 1. The distance between these elements should be the same or as similar as possible.
For this example it could look like this:
0-0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-1-0-0-1-0-0-0-1-0
Sometimes there need to be 2 zeros and somethime 3 zeros between the ones.

I can not find anything that would solve my problem and I am out of ideas, can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I need to draw a line on a rectangular grid of pixels with x2-x1=24 and y2-y1=7. The "steps" in the "line" should be spaced as evenly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are slightly ambiguous, but something along these lines should do the trick:

```
% parameters
n = 25;
m = 7;

% initialize row vector
v = zeros(1, n);

% create index of elements to set equal to 1. Include first and last
% elements, plus equally spaced elements in between.
I = 1 : (n-1)/(m-1) : n;
I = round(I);

% check that this algorithm works for these values of n and m. For
% example, m must be <= n
if length(unique(I)) ~= m
    error('Does not work for these values of n and m');
end

% set the appropriate vector elements to 1
v(I) = 1;
```